# Compiling Indvidual Modules In Gnu radio

Tags: cmake, dependencies, open-source, gnuradio

I am new to open source contribution, so after editing the source code for gnu-radio, I want to only compile the gr-qtqui module.

I ran cmake with the following flags:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DENABLE_DEFAULT=OFF -DENABLE_GR_QTGUI=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/somedir -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 ../
```

However I encountered this error:

```
-- Configuring gr-qtgui support...
--   Dependency QT_FOUND = 1
--   Dependency QWT_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency ENABLE_GNURADIO_RUNTIME = OFF
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FFT =
--   Dependency ENABLE_GR_FILTER =
--   Dependency PYTHONLIBS_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency PYQT5_FOUND = TRUE
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/GrComponent.cmake:72 (message):
  user force-enabled gr-qtgui but configuration checked failed
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  gr-qtgui/CMakeLists.txt:33 (gr_register_component)
```

After enabling both dependencies, I encountered the same error because the dependencies has dependencies. Is there any way I would compile only the file I made changes too?

Comment: **Above** the lines you show in the question post there are lines about missed ("no found") packages. You need to check that lines and install those packages. "Is there any way I would compile only the file I made changes too?" - You may **compile** specific files, but the **configuration** process (when you run `cmake`) is performed for the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

The CMake output tells you what is wrong: to build gr-qtgui, you need to have the gnuradio-runtime enabled; also, the gr-filter and gr-fft components. They are internal dependencies! You can't build gr-qtgui without building these.